# How to change default background of dropdown of select multiple

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the page whith  is loading, it is the default color in the list of options (in chrome it # c8c8c8, faerfoks in blue). How to chenge it / make transparent? I tried different combinations of pseudo-classes and js - all in vain. When you click on an option it works.  [For examle](http://jsfiddle.net/w76gLox5/):

```html
<select multiple>
   <option selected>1111111</option>
   <option selected>222222222</option>
   <option selected>33333333</option>
   <option selected>44444444</option>
</select>
```

I haven`t access to the server part, where this list is forming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the options are highlighted gray instead of blue is that they aren't in focus. When you click on an element it is focused on, so the options will be changed to blue like you want. (If you then click away from the select they will be changed back to gray). Use the `autofocus` property to focus on this element automatically.

```html
<select multiple autofocus="autofocus">
   <option selected>1111111</option>
   <option selected>222222222</option>
   <option selected>33333333</option>
   <option selected>44444444</option>
</select>
```

If you wish to change the default color schemes, use the css `focus` selector

```
select:focus {/*Add styles for in focus*/}
select:not(:focus) {/*Add styles for not in focus*/}
```

You are selecting four options, so if you only meant to select one see @KyleDumovic 's answer

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You're loading the page with four selected elements, just remove the `selected` attribute on the ones you don't want the page to load in grey.

```css
select option {
  background-color: red;
}

select option[selected] {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<select multiple>
    <option>1111111</option>
    <option>222222222</option>
    <option selected>33333333</option>
    <option>44444444</option>
</select>
```

Comment: And can`t i set background for selected item?

Comment: See my updated code snippet. In terms of changing the default active and inactive highlight color (in Chrome on OSX for me they are set to blue and grey), I don't believe you can do this with CSS as they are rendered by the OS and not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `selected` attribute on the ones you don't want the page to load in grey.